# OutOfMemory error while creating chunks of large file in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to read file and uploading it to server with 1 MB chunk size. It is working fine upto 13 MB but after that it give me OutOfMemory Exception. I have checked buffer and it is always 1MB of size but I don't know why it is getting into exception. 1 thing I predict that previous read bytes are not getting free immediately by system so I tried to find some way to free it but there is not any method with byte[] to free.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = null;
            try {
                byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[maxchunksize];
                int len = 0;
                int startpoint = 0;
                while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    Log.i("Upload Chunk",""+buffer.length);
                    byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    String uploadresponse = UploadChunk(fileHandle, buffer, startpoint, EmailID);
                    if(!uploadresponse.equals("Chunk Added"))
                    {
                        Log.e("Upload Chunk", "something went wrong. Aborting upload");
                        break;
                    }
                    startpoint += buffer.length; 

                }
```

Can any one help me to get this issue resolved? My file max size is 25MB.

this is the exception I am getting.

```
06-26 22:49:22.329: E/AndroidRuntime(15645): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-26 22:49:22.329: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91)
06-26 22:49:22.329: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
06-26 22:49:22.329: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at com.desiengineer.backgroundtask.EvidenceUploadService.onHandleIntent(EvidenceUploadService.java:101)
06-26 22:49:22.329: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
06-26 22:49:22.329: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-26 22:49:22.329: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-26 22:49:22.329: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: Are you doing it on UI thread?

Comment: no it is on IntentService.

Comment: I guess you are popping the stack memory of current thread created by `InternService` in `onHandleIntent` (notice here: `06-26 22:49:22.329: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)`). Try debug to test if your buffer logic is correct.

Comment: byteBuffer is for what purpose?  This is causing you to run out of memory...

Comment: to write chunk in buffer. Is there any other method that I can use. I have seen this code example in internet. If you know better way please post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `ByteArrayOutputStream`. You are not using it, and it is the source of your memory problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer however I figured out it while you were posting answer. ;) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code to:

```
while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    Log.i("Upload Chunk",""+buffer.length);
    byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    String uploadresponse = UploadChunk(fileHandle, buffer, startpoint, EmailID);
    if(!uploadresponse.equals("Chunk Added"))
    {
        Log.e("Upload Chunk", "something went wrong. Aborting upload");
        break;
    }
    startpoint += buffer.length; 
    byteBuffer.reset(); 
}
```

Without byteBuffer.reset() your buffer is still expanding and cause OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: My buffer was working exactly fine. the mistake I did was increasing `ByteArrayOutputStream` while I was not using it.

Comment: Ah! I expected that there is some reason for ByteArrayOutputStream to be there maybe related to some other part of the code.